# Differentiability, linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $Y$ be a complete normed linear space, and let $M$ denote the
space of bounded linear operators from $Y$ to itself. Let $L : M → M$ be the map
defined by
$L(A) := A^2$.

I am supposed to show that L is differentiable at each $A\in M$, and then find the derivatives.

Tried to find the derivatives like this:

$L'(A) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{L(A+h)-L(A)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(A+h)^2-A^2}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{A^2+2Ah-h^2-A^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 2A+h = \underline{2A}$

If this is correct, all I have to do now is to show that $L$ is differentiable at all $A\in M$, and I'm wondering if I can do that by saying that $L$ is a composition of $A$ and $A$ since $A$ is a linear operator, and all linear operators are differentiable?

Comment: The way you write things is strange... first, what is the meaning of $\frac{L(A+h)-L(A)}{h}$ in $M$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $L$ at an operator $A$ is a linear map. In this case, it is the map $\varphi$ defined by $\varphi(M)=AM+MA$. In fact\begin{align}\lim_{M\to A}\frac{\bigl\lVert L(M)-L(A)-\varphi(M-A)\bigr\rVert}{\lVert M-A\rVert}&=\lim_{M\to A}\frac{\bigl\lVert M^2-A^2-A(M-A)-(M-A)A\bigr\rVert}{\lVert M-A\rVert}\\&=\lim_{M\to A}\frac{\lVert M^2-AM-MA+A^2\rVert}{\lVert M-A\rVert}\\&=\lim_{M\to A}\frac{\bigl\lVert(M-A)^2\bigr\rVert}{\lVert M-A\rVert}\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: Can we use the notation $\lim_{M\to A}$ whereas $M$ and $A$ are operator ?

Comment: We can use it in any metric space.

Comment: No, you can't write it as $2AM$ because, in general, linear operators do not commute. And I guessed that the derivative is $\varphi$ by analysing $M^2-A^2$ and trying to determine what I should subtract from it so that$$\lim_{M\to A}\frac{\bigl\lVert M^2-A^2-\varphi(M-A)\bigr\rVert}{\lVert M-A\rVert}=0.$$

Comment: I got $AM+MA$ by doing this: $\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{L(A+\alpha M)-L(A)}{\alpha} = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{(A+\alpha M)^2-A^2}{\alpha} = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{(A^2+A\alpha M + \alpha M A + \alpha ^2 M^2 - A^2}{\alpha} = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} AM+MA+\alpha M^2 = AM+MA$. But I'm not sure if using the $\alpha$ makes any sense

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Ok, I'm surprised, I thought the space need to be at least ordered. But what would be the meaning of $\lim_{M\to A}$ ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How to show boundedness of $\phi(M) = AM+MA$?

Comment: \begin{align}\lVert AM+MA\rVert&\leqslant\lVert AM\rVert+\lVert MA\rVert\\&\leqslant\lVert A\rVert.\lVert M\rVert+\lVert A\rVert.\lVert M\rVert\\&=2\lVert A\rVert.\lVert M\rVert.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

In order to **discover** (and at the same time **prove** that $D_A(H):=AH+HA$ is the *differential* of function $L$, which is different from the *derivative*), just expand

$$L(A+H)=(A+H)^2=\underbrace{A^2}_{L(A)}+\underbrace{(AH+HA)}_{D_A(H)}+\underbrace{H^2}_{2nd \ order}$$

and collect all the first degree terms.

Do you see the connection with Taylor expansion :

$$f(a+h)=f(a)+\underbrace{f'(a).h}_{differential}+\text{terms in} \ h^2, h^3, \text{etc.} ?$$

Comment: We can proceed like this as long as we are in a **Banach algebra** which is the largest "reasonable" algebraic-topological framework in which differential calculus can be defined.